# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createCrosshairTooltips' of undefined - Kendo chart angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, charts, kendo-chart

In production environment, I got this error as stated on the title on Kendo bar chart and the chart does not appear.
What can i do to solve this issue?

I tried to remove `<kendo-chart-category-axis>` tag and the chart appears.